# Transimpedence amplifier, higher output than expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, ltspice, transimpedance

I am approaching now at LTSpice. 
My aim is to design a transimpedence amplifier in order to have V_output=I_input*1000.I mean,such an easy task.

So I tried to run my simulation, also adding a capacitor of C=4pF (obtained  considering gain bandwidth of 4MHz).
What I expected was to obtain an output voltage equal to 0.005*10000=50V (and that is what it happens if I use the ideal on e BUT I have to use this opamp (https://file.didattica.polito.it/download/MATDID/32964544) [image: spi]and the result is the following.

I really don't know why it shows this voltage and how to fix it! Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Sorry I want to say -50V

Comment: You have a 15v supply rail, so you can't get 50V out.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT! It was the most obvious problem! thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Are we all done here then?

Answer (score 0):

The output voltage is negative because of the direction of the input current and since you supply your opamp with +- 15 Volt it cant drive its output beyond that. In fact since it is not a rail to rail opamp there is a certain voltage the output stays below/above the rails. In fact the opamp is in saturation. Try feeding your circuit with a lower Input current e.g. 1mA.